# Determining the sum of a number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm not sure of the best way to ask this question but I will try with an example of my problem:

I have three numbers, `3` and `5` and `x`.

`x` always starts as zero.

There are two possible events that can occur:

- Someone buys an apple -> I add `3` to `x`
- Someone buys a banana -> I add `5` to `x`

If someone makes a purchase then I can use `mod3`, `mod5` and `mod8` to determine if they bought an apple, a banana or both.

This is fine for any number lower than `15`. Once we get to `15 and above` we do not know whether someone only bought apples, only bought bananas or bought a combination of both.

So my question is, are there any three numbers I can always use to determine if they bought just apples, just bananas or both?

Or is there a better way of doing this all together?

Comment: Why not just maintain two variables, one for each fruit?

Comment: @J.M. When I tried to answer to that comment with a "why I can't" response I realised I have completely over complicated my problem. I am going to delete the question, but thank you for making me re-think the steps that I am taking!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No, there are no such numbers. Not if you are adding.
Take any $p,q \in \mathbb{N}$. Then, at one point you may have $x = pq$ and can't decide whether that is because someone bought $q$ apples or $p$ bananas.

You can, however, do this by using multiplication. Initialize $x := 1$ and choose $p := 2$, $q := 3$ (or any other distinct primes). Multiply $x$ by $p$ or $q$ accordingly. To get the information about how much was bought, factorise $x$. I do not recommend this for practical purposes, but in theory it works fine.

Comment: After rethinking through my problem, I have decided I am over-complicating the entire issue. Thanks for the answer and since you offered an alternative solution then I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

If a,b,c are the numbers you want, a|LCM(a,b) and b|LCM(a,b), that means when c>=LCM(a,b), you will never know c whether someone only bought apples, only bought bananas or bought a combination of both.

Comment: +1 thanks :) However I am accepting the answer from @m_l as they offered an alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is the [coin problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem).  If the two values are a,b and gcd(a,b)=1, you can represent all numbers above ab-a-b-1.  Once you get to ab you can't tell whether you have a b's or b a's.

Comment: +1 thanks for the link and the almost layman explanation. It always makes me feel better when they have a name for my problem :)

Comment: @MyHeadHurts:  not only does it make you feel better to know the name of the problem, but it gives you something to search on.  I have received the same as 18 point problem for http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43311/choosing-points-in-fractions-of-the-unit-interval and found some interesting articles that way.